# Найти общие точки у графиков OxyPlot

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

У меня есть два графика, нарисованные с помощью oxyplot, шаг графиков - 0.01, графики рисуются по массивам, то есть их нельзя задать какой-либо функцией.

Каждый график состоит примерно из таких точек(сильно утрирую, главное, что шаг равен 0.01): (0,430) (0.01,415) (0.02,410) (0.03,400) (0.04,450)

Мне нужно найти общие точки у этих графиков, но вот проблема, по оси x эта точка может быть например 0.74453 или типо того, поэтому я не могу найти эту точку путем сравнения массивов. Есть ли какая-то внутренняя функция у oxyplot, которая это подсчитает?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: то есть у всех отрезков шаг один и тот же? Тогда вам на каждом шаге надо искать пересечение соответствующих отрезков, разве нет? \

Comment: Неа, это так не получается( я добавил в вопрос еще одну картинку, у точки пересечения Time шаг ну никак не 0.01. А проходить весь массив с шагом 0.000000000000001, чтобы найти эту точку как-то не очень хорошо

Comment: Там на первых двух картинках показано, при 0.78 и при 0.79 точки не пересекаются, а пересекаются при числе между 0.78 и 0.79.

Comment: так это нормально. У вас есть 2 отрезка, оба в интервале 0,78-0,79, так? Вот и ищите точку их пересечения

Comment: [Пересечение двух отрезков](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/segments_intersection)

Comment: а, понял о чем вы, спасибо)